# Sinch/Twilio iOS SDK use case

Tags: ios, twilio, twilio-api, sinch, sinch-verification

I have a use case in which I want the user to only be able to verify himself from the device that contains the sim card he is registering himself from. As this is a financial application which tracks user accounts based on their cell number. So I don't want people to share the verification code and register from another device while sending the verification code on another device. It is possible in android to enforce user to register from same device using auto-fetch but iOS does not provide this capability. Is it possible using Sinch/Twilio sdk in iOS? Pleases guide me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid it's not possible to intercept incoming SMS messages on iOS like you can on Android with the [Twilio verification SDK](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/05/twilio-verification-sdk-android-app-sms-permissions-phone-verification-has-never-been-easier.html). So this isn't possible as far as I am aware.